# How is $dx^2+dy^2$ the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

A Riemannian metric is a smooth symmetric covariant $2$-tensor field.

---

> [image]

---

If I put in two vectors, say $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$, I don't get $\|(1,2)-(2,1)\|=\sqrt{2}$:

$$(dx^2+dy^2)((1,2), (2,1))=2+2=4.$$

Comment: Put in the form $\sum g_{ij}dx^idx^j$, this form always refers to the square of the  element of length.

Comment: Who said it was? First, as you seem to be reading it, $dx^2+dy^2$ here equals $1^2+1^2=2.$ Second, that's not the definition of the Euclidean distance, either/

Comment: This form is a quadratic form, and applies to one vector only (strictly speaking, to a tangent vector at a given point but everything is the same in the flat space). Applied to $(1,2)$ you get $1^2+2^2=5$.

Comment: @GReyes But if I take the square root, I get $2$. Do I need to take square root twice?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $dx^2+dy^2= dx \otimes dx + dy \otimes dy$. So, if I put in $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$, I get $1\cdot 2 + 2\cdot 1=4$.

Comment: @GReyes $dx^2+dy^2= dx \otimes dx + dy \otimes dy$.

Comment: A metric in the Riemannian sense is not the same as a metric in the metric-space sense.

Comment: The metric applied to two vectors gives the standard dot (inner) product between them. (this is explicit in the last line of your photo). That's why you get 4 as an answer. If you want to compute the lenght of a path between two vectors, you have to do it in the "usual" calculus way: parametrize the line, and compute the integral $\int ds$

Comment: I think the whole confusion has to do with notation here. $dx^2+dy^2$ is the classical notation for the quadratic form which is associated (we would say today) to a symmetric bilinear form with matrix $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$. But in the classical sense, $dx^2+dy^2=ds^2$, the square of the element of length. I guess in tensor notation it would be the symmetric tensor mentioned by Wolfgang.

Comment: A Riemannian metric is very different indeed from a general metric. It has to be bilinear, it applies to (pairs of) tangent vectors, etc. none of which make sense in a general metric space. however, if you define on a manifold the distance to be the integral of the Riemannian metric between two points, you obtain a legitimate metric space.